# Checking For Values in string in table field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with blog posts, and i want to control display based on who's seen which article. I added a new table field in db 'post_seen' and want to append 'viewer_id' to the field (eg.: 'user5,user2,user8'). I want then be able to check if the user id is in the post seen field, to do some action.

The queries dont seem to be working So far I've done this

```
    public  function checkUnSeenPosts($myid){
              //select all posts where user_id not found in post_seen column
              $query = "SELECT * FROM mutamba_posts WHERE INSTR('post_seen',".$myid.") > 0";

                $sql = $this->db->query($query);
                if($sql->num_rows() > 0){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;

                }


         }


  function markPostsAsSeen($user_id){
        //select all posts where user_id not found in post_seen column
        $query = "SELECT * FROM mutamba_posts WHERE INSTR('post_seen',".$user_id.")< 0";

        $sql = $this->db->query($query);
        if($sql->num_rows() > 0){

            foreach ($sql->result() as $r){

                        $data = array('post_seen' => $r->post_seen.','.$user_id); 
                        $this->db->update('mutamba_posts',$data);


            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: post_seen csv field concept is a bad idea; you'd be much better of with a  post_seen table, having post_id and viewer_id fields. That said, the problem with your queries is that you are enclosing the field in quotes; no numbers are in the string "post_seen".

Comment: Another problem you'll have with this is if (for example) viewer 101 is in the list, these queries will indicate viewers 10 and 1 are as well.

Comment: @Uueerdo thanks, Will make it the right way ;)